# How can I make use of the conjugacy part of Sylow's theorem instead of the second isomorphism theorem to show this?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $P\in Syl_p(G)$. $N\unlhd G$. Use the conjugacy part of Sylow's theorem to show that $P\cap N\in Syl_p(N)$. Deduce that $PN/N\in Syl_p(G/N)$. (Abstract Algebra: Dummit & Foote, Sylow's theorem, Ex. 34)

This can be solved outright by using the second isomorphism theorem. The authors however, refer the readers back to the section introducing the isomorphism theorems where this problem was part of an exercise, and this time we have to do this once again by using 'the conjugacy part of Sylow's theorem'!:

> Let $P\in Syl_p(G)$. Let $Q$ be any $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then $Q$ is contained in some $g$-conjugate of $P$. So any two Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G$ are conjugates.

I have no idea how to employ this to solve the problem. I can't get rid of the second isomorphism theorem from my mind and now I get stuck. Can somebody at least give me a hint D: ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Q$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$. Then $Q\subseteq P'$ for some
Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Then $P=xP'x^{-1}$ for some $x$. As $N$
is normal, $N\cap P=x(P'\cap N)x^{-1}=xQx^{-1}$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup
of $N$. Then $NP/N$ is a subgroup of $G/N$ of the right order to be
a Sylow subgroup.

Comment: Your answer seems simpler.

Comment: But why would $|P'\cap N|=|Q|$?

Comment: @hellotinfish $P'\cap N\supseteq Q$, but $P'\cap N$ is a $p$-group and $Q$ is a maximal $p$-subgroup of $N$.