# An explicit example such that no $h$-conjugate of $P$ intersects $H$ at a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$ for all $h\in H$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

> Let $P\in Syl_p(G)$. $H\le G$. Prove that $gPg^{-1}\cap H\in Syl_p(H)$ for some $g\in G$. Is there an example such that $hPh^{-1}\cap H\notin Syl_p(H),$ $\forall h\in H$?

This is a follow-up of: [How can I make use of the conjugacy part of Sylow's theorem instead of the second isomorphism theorem to show this?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337617/how-can-i-make-use-of-the-conjugacy-part-of-sylows-theorem-instead-of-the-secon)

I mimicked the proof of the proposition as stated in the link above. This is the first part of the proof that $gPg^{-1}\cap H\in Syl_p(H)$ for some $g\in G$: Let $Q\in Syl_p(H)$. $Q$ is a $p$-subgroup of $G$. $P\in Syl_p(G)$, so:

> $Q\le gPg^{-1}$ for some $g\in G$.

My instinct brings me to a conclusion that this is the reason why there is an $H$ s.t. $hPh^{-1}\cap H\notin Syl_p(H),$ $\forall h\in H$. There may not be an $h\in H$ s.t. $Q\le hPh^{-1}$. **Is it the exact reason behind this?**

This comes to my mind: Let $G=\operatorname{Sym}(5)=\langle(12),(12345)\rangle$. $|G|=120=2^3*3*5$. Let $p=3$. $P=\langle(145)\rangle\in Syl_3(G)$. Let $H=\operatorname{Alt}(4)$ be the alternating group on $\{1,2,3,4\}$. We find $Q$ s.t. $Q\in Syl_3(H)$. We can let $Q=\langle(123)\rangle$.

I believe there is no such $\sigma\in \operatorname{Alt}(4)$ which satisfies $\langle(123)\rangle\le \sigma \langle(145)\rangle\sigma^{-1}$. **Is the example above valid?** I'm not confident enough to say so.

Comment: Yes the example is valid. Since $\sigma$ fixes the point $5$, $\sigma(1,4,5)\sigma^{-1}$ is a $3$-cycle containing the point $5$, and so it cannot be $(1,2,3)$ or $(1,3,2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you are right; for any $\sigma\in H$, $\sigma$ will not move $5$, but $\sigma P\sigma^{-1}$ will be generated by a $3$-cycle which *moves* $5$, and all elements of $H$  (except $1$) do not move $5$. So $\sigma P\sigma^{-1}$ can not be Sylow-$3$ **of** $H$ (but *is* of course of $G$)